# policy doesn't working in laravel in module

Tags: laravel-8

this is my Auth Service Provider :

```
   <?php

namespace App\Providers;
use App\Models\Profile;
use App\Policies\ProfilePolicy;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use RequestManager\Http\Models\RequestState;
use RequestManager\Policies\RequestStatePolicy;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
          Profile::class=>ProfilePolicy::class,
          RequestState::class=>RequestStatePolicy::class,
     ];

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

this is my policy array :

```
array:2 [
  "App\Models\Profile" => "App\Policies\ProfilePolicy"
  "RequestManager\Http\Models\RequestState" => "RequestManager\Policies\RequestStatePolicy"
]
```

I have a policy that is in its own module folder with this structure :

[image]

this is my controller :

```
  public function showDepartmentRequests($id)//id = department id
    {
        $request=RequestState::where('department_id',$id)->get();
        dd(\Gate::forUser(User::find(2))->allows('view',$request));
    }
```

and this is my policy :

```
    <?php

namespace RequestManager\Policies;
use RequestManager\Http\Models\RequestState;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
class RequestStatePolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function view(User $user, RequestState $requestState)
    {
        dd("test view policy");
     }


}
```

Nothing is printed when I call the gate!

Is this error because I have to register a policy within a specific auth service Provider
other than the app\AuthServiceProvider?

Comment: Change the name of the controller's method to "show" and see if anything changes.

Comment: @HoseinShendabadi Which  line ?

Comment: @HoseinShendabadi Do you mean to change the name of "showDepartmentRequests" method ? The method works properly , My problem is with the policy!

Comment: Yes, the view method in policy is connected to the show method of the related controller.